# How to make offline database for my app?

Tags: ios, swift, database, persistence

I am getting problem in consuming `RestAPI` and saving offline data. Is any one have best ideas about this.

I want to save JSON response from server in local database and use that data when no internet is available. like `Firebase` realtime Database.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think what are you asking for is a mechanism to persist data into your application. There are several approaches to achieve this. Although it could be too broad to provide detailed answer, you might want to check as options:

#### Databases:

- [**Core Data**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata):

> Core Data is an object graph and persistence framework provided by
> Apple in the macOS and iOS operating systems. It was introduced in Mac
> OS X 10.4 Tiger and iOS with iPhone SDK 3.0. It allows data
> organized by the relational entity–attribute model to be serialized
> into XML, binary, or SQLite stores. The data can be manipulated using
> higher level objects representing entities and their relationships.
> Core Data manages the serialized version, providing object lifecycle
> and object graph management, including persistence. Core Data
> interfaces directly with SQLite, insulating the developer from the
> underlying SQL.
>
> <sub>[Wikipedia Resource.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_Data)</sub>
>
> <sub>[Programming Guide.](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html)</sub>

- [**SQLite**](https://sqlite.org/) -with a wrapper such as [SQLite.swift](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift)-

> SQLite is a relational database management system contained in a C
> programming library. In contrast to many other database management
> systems, SQLite is not a client–server database engine. Rather, it is
> embedded into the end program.
>
> <sub>[Wikipedia resource](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite).</sub>

- [**Realm**](https://realm.io/products/realm-mobile-database/):

> Realm is an open-source object database management system, initially
> for mobile (Android/iOS), also available for platforms such as Xamarin
> or React Native, and others, including desktop applications (Windows),
> and is licensed under the Apache License.
>
> <sub>[Wikipedia resource.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realm_(database))</sub>

#### Other Alternatives:

- [**UserDefaults**](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults):

> The UserDefaults class provides a programmatic interface for
> interacting with the defaults system. The defaults system allows an
> app to customize its behavior to match a user’s preferences. For
> example, you can allow users to specify their preferred units of
> measurement or media playback speed. Apps store these preferences by
> assigning values to a set of parameters in a user’s defaults database.
> The parameters are referred to as defaults because they’re commonly
> used to determine an app’s default state at startup or the way it acts
> by default.

- Saving Data to [**plist**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_list) files:

> In the macOS, iOS, NeXTSTEP, and GNUstep programming frameworks,
> property list files are files that store serialized objects. Property
> list files use the filename extension .plist, and thus are often
> referred to as p-list files.
>
> Property list files are often used to store a user's settings. They
> are also used to store information about bundles and applications, a
> task served by the resource fork in the old Mac OS.

- Saving Data to [**json**](https://www.json.org/) files:

> In computing, JavaScript Object Notation or JSON is an open-standard
> file format that uses human-readable text to transmit data objects
> consisting of attribute–value pairs and array data types (or any other
> serializable value). It is a very common data format used for
> asynchronous browser–server communication, including as a replacement
> for XML in some AJAX-style systems.
>
> <sub>[Wikipedia resource.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)</sub>