# How to store a high score in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I was wondering how I would save a high score in Swift 3 such that one could close the app and the high score would still be there?

I am using Xcode 8.2.1

Comment: Use `UserDefaults`. https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/12/2/reading-and-writing-basics-userdefaults

Comment: use NSUserDefaults

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40278645/5501940) might be helpful to you, if your need is to save a small amount of data, I suggest to go with `UserDefaults`

Answer (score 1):

**You Can use anyone of the following :**

1. `NSUserDefaults :` At runtime, you use an NSUserDefaults object to read the defaults that your application uses from a user’s defaults database.
2. `info plist :`  An information property list is a specialized type of property list that contains configuration data for a bundle.
3. `Core data :` It provides generalized and automated solutions to common tasks associated app.
4. `Sqllite DB :` Create DB